# Sonar Views plugin does not show views in dashboard

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, view

[image]Sonar Version: 5.1
Views plugin version: 2.8

1) Go to "Settings->Configuration->Views".
2) Create a view and add two projects to the view manually.
3) Go to "Settings->Security->Project Permission" and give admin permission to the view.  I am the administrator
4) Got to Jenkins and build the two projects(maven projects) again with sonar option.
5) According to Views plugin document, I should see a "Projects" tab and right click on it, I should see a "Views" menu item.  I don't even see the "Projects" tab.
6) Go to Component:views, nothing shows up.

Can anyone help?  I want to group our projects by department and I want to see overall coverage percentage for each department.

Comment: Please contact Support for questions about commercial plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Could you let me know how to contact Sonar support, or Sonar Source support?

Comment: In such a case, the best is to contact your SonarSource Sales representative.